# In VIM, showing list where javascript function called

Tags: javascript, vim, tags

in VIM, I want to get the list where javascript function called and jump.

in case of C language, I used to use cscope to get the list and jump.

but cscope doesn't support Javascript.

hope you give me some tips.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cscope supports JavaScript: `$ cscope -R *.js`.

Comment: Javascript's syntax is close to C, but it's not identical and in particular for recent versions (ES6 and ES7) it is diverging more so cscope is fairly imprecise. Because of this I wrote an app to replace cscope with a proper javascript parser, which is a lot more accurate: https://github.com/eapache/starscope